Create Shapefile from Set of Routes in OSMNX



Place
Lat
Long




Saluhallen
57,7052433780123
11,9678099732456


Gothenburg Law Court
57,7070260802736
11,9660123575804


Göteborg Centralstasjon
57,7090180088649
11,972294301168


Sahlgrenska University Hospital
57,6829267881712
11,9619088391943


Skatås motionscentrum
57,7041859292408
12,0357343174424


Universitas Regia Gothoburgensis
57,6985173380122
11,9715930268999



I have list of locations in Gothenburg, Sweden for which I calculated a route matrix (distance shortest path from each location to all others, only in one direction). Now for a demonstration, I wish to create a shapefile of the entire set of routes, somehow I don't get how to combine all routes to a graph.
I am aware that I am supposed to use GeoPackage instead, but until now I always failed to open GeoPackage files in ArcMap. Also the problem creating the graph would remain the same...
I would be very grateful for your assistance.
My code looks as follows:
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd


city = 'Göteborg, Sweden'
graph = ox. graph_from_place(city, network_type='walk')
# locations dataframe from excel
filename = 'places.xlsx'
places = pd.read_excel(filename)

# for each place --> closest node in graph
place_nodes = []
for i in range(len(places)):
    i_lat = places["Lat"].loc[i]
    i_long = places["Long"].loc[i]
    i_node = ox.nearest_nodes(graph, i_long, i_lat, return_dist=False)
    place_nodes.append(i_node)

all_nodes = set()

for i_from in range(len(place_nodes)):
    # only one direction
    for i_to in range(i_from+1, len(place_nodes)):
        # calc route
        dist_nodes = ox.shortest_path(graph, place_nodes[i_from], place_nodes[i_to], weight='length')
        print(dist_nodes)
        # list of route edges
        dist_edges = ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(graph, dist_nodes)
        print (dist_edges)
        # route length
        length = dist_edges["length"].sum() / 1000
        print("From", places["Place"].loc[i_from], "to", places["Place"].loc[i_to], "it's", length, "km.")
        # set of all node ids without duplicates
        all_nodes.update(set(dist_nodes) - all_nodes)
        # first run
        if i_from + i_to == 1:
            all_edges = dist_edges
        # all other runs_ gdf with all edges in routes
        else:
            all_edges = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([all_edges, dist_edges], ignore_index=True))

nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)
# gdf with all nodes in routes
route_nodes = nodes.loc[all_nodes]
all_edges.set_index('osmid', inplace=True)
# create graph, then shapefile
shapegraph = ox.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(route_nodes, all_edges, graph_attrs=None)
ox.io.save_graph_shapefile(shapegraph, filepath=None, encoding='utf-8', directed=False)

I believe that reason for the error is hidden in the concatenation, as adding
.drop_duplicates()

to that line also throws an error...
Like I mentioned before, I am extremely grateful for any hint to what I did wrong.

You can just use the OSMnx route_to_gdf function then save the resulting GeoPandas GeoDataFrame as a shapefile.
